# Finding word in sentence

Tags: rust

In the following example:

```
fn main() {
  let str_vec: ~[&str] = "lorem lpsum".split(' ').collect();

  if (str_vec.contains("lorem")) {
    println!("found it!");
  }
}
```

It will not compile, and says:

```
error: mismatched types: expected &&'static str 
but found 'static str (expected &-ptr but found &'static str)
```

What's the proper way to find the word in sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
if sentence.words().any(|x| x == "ipsum") {
    println!("Found it!");
}
```

You could also do something with `.position()` or `.count()` instead of `.any()`. See [Iterator trait](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

Answer (score 5):

The [`contains()`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/trait.ImmutableEqVector.html#tymethod.contains) method on vectors (specifically, on all vectors satisfying the `std::vec::ImmutableEqVector` trait, which is for all vectors containing types that can be compared for equality), has the following signature,

```
fn contains(&self, x: &T) -> bool
```

where `T` is the type of the element in the array. In your code, `str_vec` holds elements of type `&str`, so you need to pass in a `&&str` -- that is, a borrowed pointer to a `&str`.

Since the type of `"lorem"` is `&'static str`, you might attempt first to just write

```
str_vec.contains(&"lorem")`
```

In the current version of Rust, that doesn't work. Rust is in the middle of a language change referred to as [dynamically-sized types (DST)](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/05/dst-take-5/). One of the side effects is that the meaning of the expressions `&"string"` and `&[element1, element2]`, where `&` appears before a string or array literal, will be changing (`T` is the type of the array elements `element1` and `element2`):

1. Old behavior (still current as of Rust 0.9): The expressions `&"string"` and `&[element1, element2]` are coerced to slices `&str` and `&[T]`, respectively. Slices refer to unknown-length ranges of the underlying string or array.
2. New behavior: The expressions `&"string"` and `&[element1, element2]` are interpreted as `& &'static str` and `&[T, ..2]`, making their interpretation consistent with the rest of Rust.

Under either of these regimes, the most idiomatic way to obtain a slice of a statically-sized string or array is to use the `.as_slice()` method. Once you have a slice, just borrow a pointer to that to get the `&&str` type that `.contains()` requires. The final code is below (the `if` condition doesn't need to be surrounded by parentheses in Rust, and rustc will warn if you do have unnecessary parentheses):

```
fn main() {
  let str_vec: ~[&str] = "lorem lpsum".split(' ').collect();

  if str_vec.contains(&"lorem".as_slice()) {
    println!("found it!");
  }
}
```

Compile and run to get:

```
found it!
```

---

**Edit:** Recently, a change has landed to start warning on `~[T]`, which is being deprecated in favor of the `Vec<T>` type, which is also an owned vector but doesn't have special syntax. (For now, you need to import the type from the [`std::vec_ng`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec_ng/index.html) library, but I believe the module `std::vec_ng` will go away eventually by replacing the current `std::vec`.) Once this change is made, it seems that you can't borrow a reference to `"lorem".as_slice()` because rustc considers the lifetime too short -- I think this is a bug too. On the current master, my code above should be:

```
use std::vec_ng::Vec;  // Import will not be needed in the future

fn main() {
  let str_vec: Vec<&str> = "lorem lpsum".split(' ').collect();

  let slice = &"lorem".as_slice();
  if str_vec.contains(slice) {
    println!("found it!");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not much to do with DST—it's just that for some reason unclear to me it was decided that `&"lorem"` would be equivalent to `"lorem"`, for better or for worse. You just need to take a reference to that: `& &"lorem"` (not `&&"lorem"` because `&&` will be parsed as the binary and operator).

Comment: With the latest version of Rust (14-Mar-2014), the above solution doesn't compile - "borrowed value does not live long enough" error.  @ChrisMorgan's alternative works.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan It's true that the interpretation of `&"string"` and `&[1, 2, 3]` are strictly not dependent on DST, but I was under the impression that they would have to change as a consequence of DST. I knew `&("lorem")` and `& &"lorem"` worked too, but I thought `.as_slice()` was a better solution because `.as_slice()` works no matter what strings and vectors end up being. Lucky me that the deprecation lint for `~[]` just happened to land in the rust-nightly Ubuntu package right after I answered the question!

Comment: This is super informative answer, thanks a lot! I wish I can mark it as context literature or something.